# Swift NSObject class does not reliably respond to delegate method calls

Tags: swift, xcode, nsobject, delegation

I have had a couple of instances of this recently, so I thought I'd reach out to better understand if I am doing something wrong or iOS/Xcode is just being weird.

I have a utility class, which just inherits from NSObject. My utility class holds reference to a WKWebView, and is the webview's navigationDelegate.

For the life of me, I cannot get the utility class to respond to the navigationDelegate methods, UNLESS I breakpoint at the point of setting the delegate, print out something (anything, from my testing) to the console (yep, this is important. Just breakpointing isn't enough - I have to PRINT something). Then re-run, and it responds as normal.

I am very familiar with iOS development and delegation patterns, but this is behaviour I've seen before and never understood, so I wanted to better my understanding if it's something I am getting wrong.

Here is some example code of what I am doing. It's worth noting, that if I take the utility out of the equation and just use UIViewControllers as the navigationDelegate, everything works fine.

```
class ExampleUtility: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
private weak var containerViewController: UIViewController?
private let webView: WKWebView

init(containerViewController: UIViewController) {
    self.containerViewController = containerViewController
    webView = WKWebView(frame: containerViewController.view.frame)
    super.init()
    setupWebView()
}

private func setupWebView() {
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    containerViewController?.view.addSubview(webView)
}

func start() {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webview.load(request)
}

public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // This is never called, unless I print ANYTHING to the console 
}
```

}

The fact that it responds after breakpointing and printing makes me thing its a bug of some sort? Also worth nothing that this isn't only on debug runs. It happens when not running from Xcode also.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who owns the `ExampleUtility` instances? I'm wondering if that object isn't released too soon.

Comment: Can you show how you'd use `ExampleUtility`? i.e. its caller?

Comment: Ok, interesting - that was the case. I was initialising like so at the call site:

```let util = ExampleUtility(containerViewController: self)```

I wasn't storing it as a property in the container view controller, which was my mistake. You can see by the fact I'd make containerViewController weak that my intention was to do it this way, just an oversight! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Please just keep ExampleUtility object as property in containerViewController.
Then it will work.
The reason you have this issue is, the webview instance is created in the ExampleUtility but the instance of Example Utility was already released since it is not property of containerViewController.
Please try and it will work surely.